# Automake default rule for targets with no extension?

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

Is there a generic was to specify a rule for something that goes from something with an extension to something with no extension? (in this case, '.in' to '')?

I have a project that's using automake.  I have some config file templates that need substitutions before installing them.  For example, I have a 'foo.ini.in' file that I want to use to create 'foo.ini'.  I have a few of these scattered throughout the codebase.  However, for each one, I need to create a custom Makefile rule to make them work.  Is there a better way?  I currently do this in Makefile.am:

```
bazdir=$(libdir)/@PACKAGE_NAME@/baz

EXTRA_DIST = foo.ini.in bar.ini.in
CLEANFILES = foo.ini bar.ini

foo.ini: foo.ini.in
     sed -e 's|@LIBDIR@|$(bazdir)|g' $< > $@

bar.ini: bar.ini.in
     sed -e 's|@LIBDIR@|$(bazdir)|g' $< > $@
```

This works fine, but I need to duplicate the rule for every file.  I'd like to write one rule that will do the substitution for any 'ini.in' files to 'ini' files.  I've tried:

```
%.ini.in: %.ini
     sed ....
```

but autoconf complains that % pattern substitution is a non-portable gnumake-ism.  It also doesn't like

```
.ini.in.ini: 
     sed .....
```

.. which I can't really blame it for not liking, because I can't even parse that.

Is there a way to do this?

NOTE: I can not use AC_CONFIG_FILES to do this substitution, because 'bazdir' is not fully expanded in that case.

Comment: Can you explain *why* `bazdir` cannot be fully expanded? Since `$libdir` and `$PACKAGE_NAME` variables can be set by the configure script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, there's a *much* better way: let the 'configured' files be generated from the templates using the configure script itself. As I mentioned in the comment, I don't see any reason to try to expand `$bazdir` in the `Makefile.am` itself. Maybe you can clear this up for me if there's some special reason for this.

In the `configure.ac` script, substitution variables are defined with the [**AC_SUBST**](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Setting-Output-Variables) macro. I'm guessing you want to replace `LIBDIR` with the value of `$bazdir`. Note that  `LIBDIR` isn't a good choice of name, as `libdir` is already used in configure scripts; so let's use a variable name prepended with a project name: `BAZ_LIBDIR`

**1/.** set `bazdir` in the configure script: `bazdir="${libdir}/${PACKAGE_NAME}/baz"`, and substitute with: `AC_SUBST(BAZ_LIBDIR, $bazdir)`. Alternatively, just assign the value to `BAZ_LIBDIR` and use the single argument form of `AC_SUBST`. `BAZ_LIBDIR` is now ready for substitution...

**2/.** At the end of `configure.ac`, specify the files to be generated from their `<file>.in` templates, with [**AC_CONFIG_FILES**](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Configuration-Files). Typically this will list `Makefile`'s, as well as data files, where the `.in` suffix is implicit.

Assuming a `projectdir` tree... could be any sort of tree layout of course:

```
BAZ_LIBDIR="${libdir}/${PACKAGE_NAME}/baz"
AC_SUBST(BAZ_LIBDIR)
...
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile projectdir/Makefile])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([projectdir/foo.ini projectdir/bar.ini])
...
AC_OUTPUT
```

Instances of `@BAZ_LIBDIR@` in the `<file>.ini.in` files will be replaced with the substitution value. No arcane `sed` invocations are required to generate `<file>.ini` files.

Another nice feature is that you needn't add `foo.ini.in` or `bar.ini.in` to the `EXTRA_DIST` variable in the `Makefile.am` - and `make distclean` will clean the `bar.ini` and `foo.ini` files.

Comment: Interesting. I'd prefer to keep definition of bazdir local to the Makefile.am in the directory (it's a directory of plugins that any number of people will add.. people who already grumble that the project uses Makefiles, much less autotools).  But.. .I guess they wouldn't have to.  Huh.  Thanks.